# Using malloc on double pointers inside

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct that I have coded like this...

```
typedef struct {
    double* xcoords;
    double* ycoords;
    char name[128];
    int numOfCoords;
} Image;
```

I used an Image* to dynamically allocate memory on the heap for an array of 32 Images.

```
Image* imgPointer;
imgPointer = malloc(32 * sizeof(Image));
```

I intend to use malloc on the double* xcoords and ycoords in the Image to create an array of 32 doubles, but am having difficulty figuring out how to do it.

Should this work? I'm new to C and the pointers/structs relationship is confusing...

```
// Set up arrays and increment pointer to the next struct
imgPointer->xccords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
imgPointer->ycoords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
imgPointer++;
```

Comment: Why `malloc(32 * sizeof(double))` instead of `typedef struct {
    double xcoords[32];
    double ycoords[32];
    char name[128];
    int numOfCoords;
} Image;` If it's always `32` ...

Comment: That works, but don't `++` the `imgPointer` itself. Instead, set `Image *tmp = imgPointer`, and then do `tmp->xcoords = ... ` and so on, and finally `tmp++`. This way you would retain a pointer to the original `imgPointer` array that you have allocated.

Comment: I can't actually hardcode the 32 elements. The struct array and the arrays inside the struct have to be able to keep growing by calling realloc when they get full.

Comment: yes it works, but your objective is not clear, so you may get unexpected results. please include your objective in the question.

Comment: Recommend rather than `pointer = malloc(N * sizeof(*pointer_type));`, use `pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * N);`  (sizeof variable vs. sizeof type) Easier to maintain, less chance to code wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
// Set up arrays and increment pointer to the next struct
imgPointer->xccords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
imgPointer->ycoords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
imgPointer++;
```

That will lead to problems.

**Problem 1:** You have not allocated memory for the internal data of all the `Image`s. You have allocated memory for the internal data of only the first `Image`.

**Problem 2:** You have changed the value of the pointer. It does not point to the memory that was returned by `malloc`. Calling `free` on the changed pointer value will cause undefined behavior. Not calling `free` results in memory leak.

**One solution**

```
// Allocate memory for the internal data of the Images
for ( int i = 0; i < 32; ++i )
{
   imgPointer[i].xccords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
   imgPointer[i].ycoords = malloc(32 * sizeof(double));
}
```

After you are done using the objects, deallocate memory.

```
// Free the internal data of the Images
for ( int i = 0; i < 32; ++i )
{
   free(imgPointer[i].xccords);
   free(imgPointer[i].ycoords);
}

// Free the array of Images
free(imgPointer);
```

**A cleaner solution**

Since the internal data are arrays of 32 doubles, you can change the struct to

```
typedef struct {
    double xcoords[32];
    double ycoords[32];
    char name[128];
    int numOfCoords;
} Image;
```

Then, there won't be the need to use `malloc` to allocate memory for them and to use `free` to dellocate the memory.

You can also create an array of `Image`s since you know the size.

```
Image images[32];
```

Then, there won't be the need to use `malloc` to create an array of `Image`s, and there won't be the need to `free` the allocated memory.

Comment: @ColinSpencely `.` will work because `images[0]` is not a pointer but a struct variable .